# How can I get a previous row from where the condition is met in data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For instance, I have a data frame below, I want to get the timestamp from the previous row where the Value is 1

```
    TIME    VALUE
0   23:01   0
1   23:02   0
2   23:03   1
3   23:04   0
4   23:05   0
5   23:06   1
6   23:07   0
7   23:08   0
8   23:09   0
9   23:10   0
10  23:11   1
11  23:12   0
12  23:13   0
13  23:14   0
14  23:15   0
15  23:16   1
```

I want to get the following as an output

```
    PREV_TIME
0   23:02
1   23:05
2   23:10
3   23:15
```

I don't know where to put `shift(1)` in the following

```
PREV_TIME = df['Time'][(df.Value == 1)]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call `shift` on 'VALUE' column and pass this as the condition:

```
In [7]:
df.loc[df['VALUE'].shift(-1)==1, 'TIME']

Out[7]:
1     23:02
4     23:05
9     23:10
14    23:15
Name: TIME, dtype: object
```

To add a new column 'PREV Time' alongside the row where the condition is met:

```
In [21]:
df['Prev_Time'] = df.loc[df['VALUE'].shift(-1)==1, 'TIME']
df['Prev_Time'] = df['Prev_Time'].shift()
df

Out[21]:
     TIME  VALUE Prev_Time
0   23:01      0       NaN
1   23:02      0       NaN
2   23:03      1     23:02
3   23:04      0       NaN
4   23:05      0       NaN
5   23:06      1     23:05
6   23:07      0       NaN
7   23:08      0       NaN
8   23:09      0       NaN
9   23:10      0       NaN
10  23:11      1     23:10
11  23:12      0       NaN
12  23:13      0       NaN
13  23:14      0       NaN
14  23:15      0       NaN
15  23:16      1     23:15
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It works! Can I BTW ask how can I still get the TIME (where Value is 1)  together with PREV_TIME? Or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: `df.loc[df['VALUE']==1, 'TIME']`

Comment: I meant... TIME  and PREV_TIME together, side by side... i.e. 23:03 (as TIME and ) 23:02 (as PREV_TIME)  in one row where the VALUE == 1

Comment: You can just do `df.loc[df['VALUE'].shift(-1)==1, 'TIME'],df.loc[df['VALUE']==1, 'TIME']` to see the 2 cols side by side

Comment: Ahan... sorry, then we had misunderstanding. I meant to get, in the same first answer, the 4 output rows are representing "PREV_TIME". I wanted to combine, as a column, the Original time as well. That is, (ORIGINAL)TIME  PREV_TIME. But the output stays the same, 4 rows!

Comment: call `.dropna()` on my answer to get that