# How can I get a previous row from where the conditions are met in data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have very similar question to the one on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339679/how-can-i-get-a-previous-row-from-where-the-condition-is-met-in-data-frame-in-pa) , with only difference being to have multiple conditions met.

Let us assume that we have (sorted) dataframe, similar to the one in the example, with extra column:

```
    TIME    VALUE    EXTRA_FILTER
0   23:01   0        A
1   23:02   0        A
2   23:03   1        A
3   23:04   0        B
4   23:05   0        B
5   23:06   1        B
6   23:07   0        A
7   23:08   0        A
8   23:09   0        A
9   23:10   0        A
10  23:11   1        A
11  23:12   0        A      
12  23:13   0        A
13  23:14   0        A
14  23:15   0        A
15  23:16   1        A
```

And I would like to have extra column called PREV_TIME next to each of the rows, which will contain the previous value of TIME column where both conditions to have the column VALUE equals to 1, and column EXTRA_FILTER equals to A are met, something like this:

```
TIME    VALUE    EXTRA_FILTER    PREV_TIME
0   23:01   0        A            
1   23:02   0        A
2   23:03   1        A
3   23:04   0        B
4   23:05   0        B
5   23:06   1        B
6   23:07   0        A
7   23:08   0        A
8   23:09   0        A
9   23:10   0        A
10  23:11   1        A             23:03
11  23:12   0        A      
12  23:13   0        A
13  23:14   0        A
14  23:15   0        A
15  23:16   1        A             23:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas.Series.shift`:

```
df["PREV_TIME"] = df[df["VALUE"].eq(1) & df["EXTRA_FILTER"].eq("A")]["TIME"].shift()
df["PREV_TIME"].fillna("", inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     TIME  VALUE EXTRA_FILTER PREV_TIME
0   23:01      0            A          
1   23:02      0            A          
2   23:03      1            A          
3   23:04      0            B          
4   23:05      0            B          
5   23:06      1            B          
6   23:07      0            A          
7   23:08      0            A          
8   23:09      0            A          
9   23:10      0            A          
10  23:11      1            A     23:03
11  23:12      0            A          
12  23:13      0            A          
13  23:14      0            A          
14  23:15      0            A          
15  23:16      1            A     23:11
```

Comment: This works, thanks! May I ask a subquestion: What if I didn't know the value in EXTRA_FILTER column, but I want to match it with previous one, for the same 1 in VALUE column. For example to match A with A, B with B and so on? In my brain it looks like df.loc[df['EXTRA_FILTER'] == df['EXTRA_FILTER']] but i know it makes no logical sense (1==1 basically).

Comment: @3MAJ86 I feel like that will require a completely different approach. I'd suggest asking another question with a new sample and expected output. After all, a comment section is never a good place to ask a question :P

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, and as @Chris said, it requires different approach. What I did is that I created new column that contain previous values, and did the merge with the subset of the data from the same data frame.